# Why does the 3 sum algorithm only look at sub arrays that are to the right of a particular number?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am looking at a code that solves the 3sum problem by building upon the 2sum solution. Why should low be `int lo = index+1` ? Does this mean that when we are looking at subarrays , we are only interested in the sum of the numbers to right of target ? What about the numbers to the left of the target ?

```java
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        if (nums == null || nums.length < 2) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(nums);

        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0 && nums[i - 1] == nums[i]) {
                continue;
            }
            results.addAll(twoSum(nums, i));
        }
        return results;
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> twoSum(int[] nums, int index) {
        List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();

        int target = -nums[index];
        int lo = index+1, hi = nums.length-1;
        while (lo < hi) {
            if (target == nums[lo] + nums[hi]) {
                List<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(nums[lo], nums[hi], -target);
                results.add(result);
                lo++;
                hi--;

                while (lo < hi && nums[lo] == nums[lo - 1])
                    lo++;  // skip same result
                while (lo < hi && nums[hi] == nums[hi + 1])
                    hi--;  // skip same result
            } else if (target < nums[lo] + nums[hi]) {
                hi--;
            } else {
                lo++;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because target is to the right of any number that's to the left of target.

Comment: `results.addAll(twoSum(nums, i))` ... Why are they passing i+1 to this method , what about the numbers to the left of i ?

Comment: Imagine the array is `{A,B,C,D}` where each letter represents a number. So when `threeSum` reaches A it's going to ask `twoSum` whether A works with `B+C` or `B+D`. Now when `threeSum` reaches B, do we care about A? No! We already checked whether B works with A.

Comment: This is exactly where I am stuck. Why shouldn't we care about A ?   Is there a combination out there such that A + C = B ? . If not why ?

Comment: Oh, the point of the 3 sum problem is to find any three numbers that add up to zero, i.e. `A+B+C = 0`.  Notice that the `target` is `-nums[index]`. So you're looking for `-A = B+C` which is the same as `A+B+C = 0`. And then you would be looking for `-B = A+C` which is also `A+B+C = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Because for every number `num[i]` at position `i`, you can use 2-sum algorithm on the array `[i+1...N]` to find two numbers such that their sum is equal to `-num[i]`, which means the sum of 3 numbers is 0.

For e.g.

Let the array be `[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]`

The algorithm will find any 2-sums in `[0, 1, 2, -1, -4]` is equal to `1`

Then it will find any 2-sums in `[1, 2, -1, -4]` is equal to `0`

etc.

Now you can see the starting point of the sub-array is `i+1` when you searching 2-sums for `num[i]`, which is why `int lo = index + 1`

The search is exhausive so all tuples which sum is equal to `0` will be found.